# responsive web design media query width not changing

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, flexbox

I am working on making a page responsive, by changing div `width` according to the size, but except  width every property I am able to change, `width` is not changing at all.

My code for HTML and styling the elements

```css
#main {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#main div {
  width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  #red {
    display: none;
  }
  body {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  #blue {
    width: 75%;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="red" style="background-color: red;">RED COLOR</div>
    <div id="blue" style="background-color: blue;">BLUE COLOR</div>
    <div id="green" style="background-color: orange;">GREEN color</div>
  </div>
```

This is the code I tried, but except `width` every property I am able to change How do I change the `width` property?

Answer (score 4):

don't use inline styles (that's a bad practice), and this is all about specificity, so you can set just `div` (for `width:100%`) or specify your `#blue` even more, by adding a parent to it, in this case `#main`.

You can calculate specificity [here](https://specificity.keegan.st/)

```css
#main {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
div {
  width: 100%;
}
#red {
  background: red
}
#blue {
  background: blue
}
#green {
  background: green
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  #red {
    display: none;
  }
  body {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  #blue {
    width: 75%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="red">RED COLOR</div>
  <div id="blue">BLUE COLOR</div>
  <div id="green">GREEN color</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your `#main div` styles are more specific than your `#blue` styles.

Change your media query styles to

```
#main #blue{
  width: 75%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add viewport meta tag after starting head tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

A  viewport element gives the browser instructions on how to control the page's dimensions and scaling.

This tag is important for responsiveness of webpage.
It controls your webpage width according to screen size.

Read more http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Answer (score 0):

Your #main div has precedence over your #blue div since it is defined outside the media query. If you want to apply width: 75% to only #blue div use max-width, attribute as:

```
#blue {
 max-width: 75%;
}
```

Working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/99rgto2h/)

Answer (score 0):

I was just having this problem and nothing helped me. I tried moving the media query to the end of my CSS file, and everything worked.